# Can Individual Guild Influence Be Tracked?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In the guild log it shows influence gains grouped together, but its clear from how achievements work that the single member's influence is tracked down somehow, but I don't see where it's shown.

Is there a way to see how much influence a specific guild member generated for you guild?

Comment: It's not currently possible from a guild perspective but there is an achievement track which logs how much influence you've contributed to the guild. Up to 10k inf. http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Community

Comment: Doesn't that achievement sum the influence you've contributed for all the guilds you're into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, its currently not possible to see how much influence a specific person has collected.
I'm not sure but i think it will be added in the future.

The guild log tracks the amount of influence that is collected by all guild members, since every guild member is automatically collecting guild influence by completing events and the game checks once every 24 hours for members who have logged on and represented the guild during the previous 24 hours.

Comment: That clearly generates problems when you need to know who to promote based on influence generated, but thanks for your answer... :)

Comment: @Frhay Yes it does. I heard some other people complain about it aswell.. Perhaps you can make a suggestion on the forums of GW2.